# Rewrite Nginx with $1 argument

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite an url to another one, but i can't use the $1 correctly:

```
location ~ ^/announce {
    rewrite ^(.*)$1 http://exemple.com/$1/announce.php?ip=$remote_addr&$args;
}
```

In fact `http://jack.exemple.com:2052/anything/announce` should become `https://exemple.com/anything/announce.php?ip=$remote_addr&`

That's work without the `$1`, but not with args beetwin `http://jack.exemple.com:2052/` and `/announce`

I think it's something pretty simple, but not so common, and I can't find the good syntax.

Comment: What does "but not with args between `http://jack.exemple.com:2052/` and `/announce` mean exactly? Please show a clear example what is the source URL, and what exactly you want to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved my problem with this syntax:

```
rewrite ^(.*)$ $1?ip=$remote_addr&$args break;
```

I just add `?ip=$remote_addr&$args` at the end of my URL.
For information, this is for transfer real ip from host to client, passing by cloudflare.

Comment: You should use nginx `set_real_ip` directive to make nginx use the IP in the header Cloudflare adds to the request. This way you can get the correct client IP everywhere in your setup.

Comment: Yes I did it! But the thing is, this directive works to get the correct client IP on the server, but not to send this same IP from server to client! So we need to rewrite the IP to send it to client